# When you go to save the Krogan do the Brutes keep spawning?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So right before you disperse the cure or don't, you have to tap 2 hammers to summon the Thresher Maw. Now right before that, I was attacked by a brute, so I started shooting at him and before I knew it there was another brute.

Now after dodging and weaving a third brute came, killing both my squadmates at which point, I started to run as fast as I could. After getting to the first hammer, I was surrounded by at least 5 brutes... now my question is can you kill them all and go do the tapping at peace? Or do they just keep spawning and the point is to keep running?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I got 3 Brutes right away and rapidly realized I couldn't kill 'em fast enough.  I just ran for the hammers instantly and let my squadmates do what they could to the Brutes, and that worked... but I have no idea if the Brutes are actually "beatable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I didn't realize that you were supposed to ignore the brutes the first time, and was doing my best to dodge the attacks of all 6.

What I quickly realized (after whittling down two), is that every time you kill a brute, a replacement drops down from the air. That was what made me realize, "oh, maybe I *should* go pull the hammers".

Comment: I am playing on Insanity and it happened to me a lot, that the enemies just overran me until I tried to push forward. Although I would prefer some kind of hint to do so, I recommend trying to be more offensive - Vanguard abilities would help you making presure on the enemy.

Comment: they do stop spawning,, at least they did for me.  First time I reached there I didn't realize either, I just kept fighting till they all died (go go vanguard), then all I had to do was walk up to the hammer (dodging the reaper) and pull the switch.